# Delete Duplicate VBA macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I am using a very simple simple delete duplicate macro but its prompting me to select a column. It'll always be exactly the same column and it even highlights it but still asks me to confirm. I would like for it just to remove the duplicates.

```
Sub remove()
    Columns("D:D").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$K$676").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=4, Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

https://ibb.co/3NhSYG9

Comment: Maybe you should specify something like `Columns:=Array(4)`.

Comment: This only happens in office 365 I just tried it in 2013 and it didn't do it :-/

Comment: Are you suggesting I replace Columns:=4 with Columns:=Array(4)?

Comment: Yes, this seems to fit better the latest documentation.

Comment: Remove the `Range.Select` first line. Rule of thumb, you don't need to `.Select` anything to work with a range.